# Getter setter in C# VS2017

Tags: oop, encapsulation, getter-setter, visual-studio-2017

I've been starting to use VS2017 Community. This bugs me:

Below is normal getter setter from previous VS:

```
public string Name
    {
        get{ return _name;}
        set{ _name = value;}
    }
```

This is the new getter setter:

```
public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
```

Anyone can explain to me why the syntax is changed?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say they changed it, I would say they gave us some new syntax options. You can still use the "old" way of declaring getters and setters, but there is now also a more functional programming style of doing it as well. In C#6 Microsoft already introduced using expressions for getter only properties doing:

```
public int SomeProp => someMethod();
```

C#7 enhanced this support allowing it to be used for getters AND setters. One nice feature of this is with the new "throw expressions" feature which allows us to make some concise syntax. For example, before you had to do.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Name));
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

We can now simplify this to:

```
private string _name;
public string Name { 
    get => _name; 
    set => _name = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Name)); 
}
```

Granted, you could do the throw expression even without making the setter a lambda, but as you can see, for simple things, it makes the syntax very concise.

As with anything, use the syntax that makes the most sense to you and is most readable for the people who will be coding your application. Microsoft has been making a push to add more and more functional programming style features to C# and this is just another example of that. If you find it ugly/confusing/not needed, you can absolutely accomplish everything you need with the existing method. As another example, why do we have `while` and `do while` loops? I can honestly say I've used a `do while` loop maybe 5 times in my career. A `while` loop can do everything a `do while` can just with different syntax. However, there are sometimes where you realize that using a `do while` will make your code more readable, so why not use it if it makes things easier to follow?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax hasn't changed: it has been improved. C# has been always backwards-compatible with syntax and grammar from previous versions.

*Why property getters/setters can be implemented with lambda syntax (expression-bodied accessors)?* Probably there's no scientific reason to do so, but there's a consensus about introducing useful functional programming constructs in C# as it turns the language into a more productive tool.

Just foillow up C#'s evolution since C# 2.0:

- From delegates provided as *regular methods* **to anonymous delegates**.
- LINQ, lambda-style delegates/expression trees.
- Expression-bodied methods.
- ...and expression-bodied accessors! And probably future C# versions will introduce even more functional programming-style syntax and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice they removed the 'return' syntax, this was done (from what I've read) to make it more clear that they aren't functions (and when reflected can't be treated as functions and can't be made into delegates) but rather this kind of 'pseudo-function' (if you get what I'm trying to well get at).

So basically its to make it more clear that the `getter is linking this this variable` and the repeating for the setter.  It also is because in newer versions you can do something like

`public int MyInt => x ? y:z;`

Which represents

```
public int MyInt
{
    get
    {
        return x ? y:z;
    }
}
```

Also both syntax should work, its just a new syntax that they added to bring it in line with the above example.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am adding this details after a year, but just understood that my VS 2017 generated new syntax on my web user control, and that does not reflect on the aspx file when I wanted to set a value for it.

like 
    private bool _ShowBankDetailPanel = false; //To Show Bank details section in registration
    public bool ShowBankDetailPanel { get => _ShowBankDetailPanel; set => _ShowBankDetailPanel = value; }

and on ASPX side you will NOT have property like

it is only recognize

old style getter setter....(I experience this,,, but I am be wrong)